# Is it possible to improve converting list to sorted map?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Now I have such method:

```
public static Map<String, Long> getSortedMap(List<String> wordsList) {
    Map<String, Long> countedWords = wordsList.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
            );
    return new TreeMap<>(countedWords);
}
```

which convert list of strings to map, where the key is unique string from the list, and the value - the number of times this string is repeated in the list. Then it sorts the map by key.

1. Can this be rewritten in one stream operation?
2. Is it possible to increase speed of execution?

Comment: It’s an implementation detail, but in the current version, `Collectors.summingLong(x -> 1L)` might be faster than `Collectors.counting()`. Since this is about to change in the next release, you should use that knowledge only, if you have a real performance issue, as it’s strongly recommended to revise the code upon the next Java release then.

Comment: @Holger nice! I've just checked the sources and indeed `counting` delegates to `summingLong` in 9; while in 8 `counting` it's a reducing operation with *potentially* lots of boxing and un-boxing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) variant that takes a `mapFactory` as an argument:

```
public static Map<String, Long> getSortedMap(List<String> wordsList) {
    return wordsList.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                          TreeMap::new,
                                          Collectors.counting())
            );
}
```